# How to escape ANSI format on remote SSH command?

Tags: ssh, windows

I wanted to change the title of the window using the command as described [here](https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/how-to-set-the-putty-window-title-via-script/) over SSH, however I kept get getting the error:

```
033]sh: Hello: command not found
Connection to host closed.
```

with the command:

```
ssh.exe user@host -t 'echo -en "\033];Hello World\007"'
```

No matter how I try to escape them, it seems to somehow return error. Tried:

```
ssh.exe user@host -t 'echo -en "\\033];Hello World\\007"'
ssh.exe user@host -t "echo -en \'\\033];Hello World\\007\'"
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Works here on a Linux Debian client: the remote execution temporarily changes the terminal's title (I have to add a sleep command right after, or the `$PS1` variable resets it). I suspect your *local* side, running Windows, doesn't support it, and might also be causing troubles with quotes.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: [PowerShell stripping double quotes from command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714165/powershell-stripping-double-quotes-from-command-line-arguments) - so you either need to escape the double quotes: `'echo -en \"\033];Hello World\007\"` or escape **all** shell-special characters, including the `;`: `'echo -en "\\033]\;Hello World\\007"` (in which case you may as well omit the double quotes altogether, I think).

Comment: Or just create a script on the remote side with the commands, so you don't have any quote to escape. Then you can check if the *local* terminal accepts ANSI sequences.

Comment: Huh, using script on remote definitely works, might have to stick with that for now since it's probably as you mentioned due to the Windows local. Followed suggestion by  steeldriver didn't works either. Thanks for the helps!